# Other than changing appearance, what does the Schooling ability do?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-seventh-generation

[Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/schooling.shtml) describes the ability as

> Changes the Pokémon's form when it is Level 20 and has more than 25% Hit Points. When Hit Points drop below 25%, it changes back to Solo Form

Does this ability affext anything other than asthetics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

School Form has way better base stats, as listed on Serebii's [Wishiwashi Pokedex page](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-sm/746.shtml):

Normal Form:

- HP: 45
- Attack: 20
- Defense: 20
- Special Attack: 25
- Special Defense: 25
- Speed: 40

School Form:

- HP: 45
- Attack: 140
- Defense: 130
- Special Attack: 140
- Special Defense: 135
- Speed: 30

Comment: Ah, they've added the info to that page rather than the ability's page. Seen as though this is the only Pokemon that currently gets the ability, that's fair. Though I'm curious if another Pokemon copied the ability would there be any change in stats?

Comment: @PhilD.: Schooling can't be copied.

Comment: @user2357112 To further expand on that, any moves that would copy/transfer schooling either to or from Wishiwashi will fail.